# I need to write an if statement that compares the size of 2 matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
Matrix_A=input('Enter your dimensions')
Matrix_B=input('Enter your dimensions')

If Matrix_A ~= dimensions of Matrix_B 

disp('Please enter matrices of equal dimensions')
```

Comment: What does the user enter? The matrix size, or the content of the matrix? Please add an example what the user enters and what should happen. Please also tell us what your code exactly should do and where you are struggling.

Comment: Content of the matrix e.g. matrix A= [1,2,3,4] matrix B=[4,5,6,7].

Comment: My code is meant to have 2 matrices as the input then check that the dimensions are suitable for multiplication. I am now trying to write a function that manually multiplies the matrix using loops.

Answer (score 1):

To test if two arrays `A` and `B` have the same size, use

```
isequal(size(A), size(B))
```

This works even if the arrays `A` and `B` have **different numbers of dimensions** (in which case using `size(A)==size(B)` would give an error). For example,

```
>> A = rand(2,3);
>> B = rand(3,4,5);
>> isequal(size(A), size(B))
ans =
     0
```

Comment: >> This is great too!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is `size` function in Matlab returns array dimensions:

```
if size(matrix_A) ~= size(matrix_B)
    disp('AH CMON!');
end
```

You can get more examples here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html

Comment: `size` returns a vector so you should really enclose that in an `any` i.e. `any(size(matrix_A) ~= size(matrix_B))` otherwise it can shortciruit early...

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.